# Mapping hash maps to class instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Looking for gem or at least idea how to approach this problem, the ones I have are not exactly elegant :)

Idea is simple I would like to map hashes such as:

```
{ :name => 'foo',
  :age  => 15,
  :job => {
        :job_name => 'bar',
        :position => 'something'
    ...
  }
}
```

To objects of classes (with flat member structure) or Struct such as:

```
class Person {
  @name
  @age
  @job_name
  ...
}
```

Thanks all.

Comment: I have a `Hash#to_ostruct` method in my personal extension library: http://rubydoc.info/gems/shenanigans/1.0.5/Hash:to_ostruct It also handles nested arrays and hashes correctly. It's not a solution for this specific problem, but you might find it interesting.

Comment: @MichaelKohl :) very elegant solution (found it on git). You should post it as answer.

Comment: @MichaelKohl Won't the code fail for array elements that are not hash? Probably I missing something ...

Comment: This part I do not understand:
when Array
 [k, v.map(&:to_ostruct)] -> This will work if elements of array are hash maps, but if it is String for example it should fail since there is no method "to_ostruct" for String, right?

Comment: You are obviously right, I just misread my own code. That's what you get for doing things in a rush... Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help, obvious answer here is as always unit testing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you can be certain sub-entry keys won't conflict with containing entry keys, here's some code that should work...

```
require 'ostruct'

def flatten_hash(hash)
  hash = hash.dup
  hash.entries.each do |k,v|
    next unless v.is_a?(Hash)
    v = flatten_hash(v)
    hash.delete(k)
    hash.merge! v
  end
  hash
end

def flat_struct_from_hash(hash)
  hash = flatten_hash(hash)
  OpenStruct.new(hash)
end
```

Comment: Very nice, bellow is my solution which handles sub-key problem but no flat structure.

Comment: Aside: I've come to prefer `o.is_a?(<class>)` over `<class> === o` because it works better with duck-type coding. Any class can override the #is_a? method to return true for any class or classes that it intends to be substitutable for.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that I used it solves problem with same key names but it does not give flat class structure. Somebody might find this handy just keep in mind that values with reserved names such as *id*, *type* need to be handled.

```
   require 'ostruct'

   def to_open_struct(element)
     struct = OpenStruct.new
     element.each do |k,v|
       value = Hash === v ? to_open_struct(v) : v
       eval("object.#{k}=value")
     end
     return struct
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate answer where you know the keys before hand

```
class Job
  attr_accessor :job_name, :position

  def initialize(params = {})
    self.job_name = params.fetch(:job_name, nil)
    self.position = params.fetch(:position, nil)
  end
end

class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :age, :job

  def initialize(params = {})
    self.name = params.fetch(:name, nil)
    self.age = params.fetch(:age, nil)
    self.job = Job.new(params.fetch(:job, {}))
  end
end


hash = { :name => 'foo', :age => 1, :job => { :job_name => 'bar', :position => 'soetmhing' }}
p = Person.new(hash)

p.name
==> "foo"

p.job
==> #<Job:0x96cacd8 @job_name="bar", @position="soetmhing">

p.job.name
==> "bar"
```